# How to handle multiple input file arguments using getopts

Tags: bash, arguments, getopts

I'm trying to make script for multiple input data files. What is the best way, how to handle that arguments? Usage of script should be:

```
./script.sh -a sth -b sth - c sth -d sth input1 input2 input3
```

I can handle parameters and arguments using getopts, but I have no idea, how to handle these input files, because there is no flag for them.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) i=$OPTARG ;;
    b) j=$OPTARG ;;
    c) k=$OPTARG ;;
    d) l=$OPTARG ;;
  esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))


for file in "$@"; do
  # your stuff here
done
```

Please try this, this may solve the purpose for you

My own comment has prompted me to extend the answer:

In case you want to do it **only from getopts:**
You will have to call the script as

`./script -a hj -b op -c zx -d some -f "File in list seperated with spaces"`

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:f:" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) i=$OPTARG ;;
    b) j=$OPTARG ;;
    c) k=$OPTARG ;;
    d) l=$OPTARG ;;
    f) files=$OPTARG ;;
  esac
done
                      #no shift is required now, since we have file list in $files
for file in $files; do
  # your stuff here
done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Can I ask you to explain, how does it work? I understand that shift, but I don't know, how does that "for file cycle" works (how is it possible, it ignores other arguments and looks just for that last arguments)?

Comment: No actually as per your question you were looking for handling everything from getopts, I have added an extra `for loop` :). For explaination part: 
read on shifting the cmdline arguments(`shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))`), you will understand how `$@` got only the desired files you ever wanted.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the second version, as it cannot deal with files with whitespace or certain other characters in their filenames. Let `getopts` handle the options, and leave the non-optional arguments in `$@` for later processing.

Comment: yeh but it can come handy when, script has two such params asking for a list like `script -d some1 -f something -p "list of files" -j "list of files"`